# Building a select distinct on mysql ( zend_db)

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I HAVE THE FOLLOWING TABLE, I WOULD LIKE TO GET to do a select distinct on the the column [code], i don't need to get the "A" three times.

```
[ ID ]   [ CODE ]     [ LIBELLE ]
1         A        LIBELLE1  
2         B        LIBELLE2
3         C        LIBELLE3
4         A        LIBELLE4  
5         A        LIBELLE5
6         D        LIBELLE6
```

I want the result as following

```
[ ID ] [ CODE ] [ LIBELLE ]
1         A        LIBELLE1  
2         B        LIBELLE2
3         C        LIBELLE3
6         D        LIBELLE6
```

Comment: i just cant understand your format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just add**

```
group by code 
ORDER BY code ASC
```

at end of your sql query

***example***

```
select * from table
group by code 
ORDER BY code ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT Min(Id) Id, Code, MIN(Libelle) Libelle
 from table
 group by code
```

Comment: am gonna test it, it seems very clever this method

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for Zend_Db_Select usage, here it is

```
$db->select()->from('table', array(
    'Id' => new Zend_Db_Expr('Min(ID)'),
    'Code' => 'CODE',
    'Libelle' => new Zend_Db_Expr('Min(LIBELLE)')
))->group('CODE');
```

`$db` should be your `Zend_Db_Adapter`.